# OnNavigatedTo is not invoked when navigating to a view in module

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, navigation, prism

I'm new to Prism and trying to make a simple modular app with it (see the [full code](https://github.com/h-Ebr/ModularSample1)).

I'm actually trying to pass a parameter to a view, so in the `ModuleAViewViewModel` of the `ModuleAView` I'm implementing `INavigationAware`, this way:

```cs
public class ModuleAViewViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private int passedId;

    public int PassedId
    {
        get => passedId;
        set => SetProperty(ref passedId, value);
    }

    // In the following 3 methods, a breakpoint never gets hit.

    public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        PassedId = (int)navigationContext.Parameters["Id"];
    }
}
```

This is the corresponding `ModuleAView`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ModularSample1.Modules.ModuleA.Views.ModuleAView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ModularSample1.Modules.ModuleA.Views"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:ModularSample1.Modules.ModuleA.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <viewmodels:ModuleAViewViewModel x:Key="moduleAViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource moduleAViewModel}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock 
            Grid.Row="1"
            Text="{Binding PassedId, StringFormat='Passed Id: {0}'}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="34"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the ViewModel that actually navigates to that view looks like this:

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;

    public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IModuleManager moduleManager)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;

        moduleManager.Run();
        Modules = moduleManager.Modules.ToList();
    }

    private List<IModuleInfo> modules;
    private IModuleInfo selectedModule;

    public List<IModuleInfo> Modules
    {
        get => modules;
        set => SetProperty(ref modules, value);
    }

    public IModuleInfo SelectedModule
    {
        get => selectedModule;
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref selectedModule, value))
            {
                var Id = new Random().Next(1, 12);
                var navigationParameters = new NavigationParameters
                {
                    { "Id", Id }
                };

                regionManager.RequestNavigate(
                    "SelectedModuleRegion",
                    $"{selectedModule.ModuleName}View",
                    navigationParameters);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define the view model for your `ModuleAView` in its `Resources` and set it on a child `Grid` via reference. Prism looks for the `DataContext` **on the view itself** to call a view model that implements `INavigationAware`, not a child control, so it does not find your view model. From the documentation:

> During navigation, Prism checks to see whether the view implements the `INavigationAware` interface; if it does, it calls the required methods during navigation. Prism also checks to see whether the object set as **the view's `DataContext`** implements this interface; if it does, it calls the required methods during navigation.

In order to make it work, set the data context directly on the `ModuleAView` and remove it from `Grid`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ModularSample1.Modules.ModuleA.Views.ModuleAView"
             ...>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewmodels:ModuleAViewViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <!-- ...grid definitions. -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

A *better* alternative is to remove setting the data context manually completely from your `ModuleAView` and register your `ModuleAView` directly with `ModuleAViewViewModel`. Prism's navigation service will automatically resolve the view model during navigation and assign it as data context.

```
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ModuleAView, ModuleAViewViewModel>();
```

You can even simplify this, by following the naming conventions for views and view models regarding the `ViewModelLocator`, which will be used in navigation to resolve view models for views.

- ViewModels are in the same assembly as the view types
- ViewModels are in a `.ViewModels` child namespace
- Views are in a `.Views` child namespace
- ViewModel names correspond with view names and end with "`ViewModel.`

You violate the last rule, so renaming `ModuleAViewViewModel` to `ModuleAViewModel` and just removing the manual setting of the data context will enable Prism to automatically find the corresponding view model for the view that you registered with `RegisterForNavigation`.

```
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ModuleAView>();
```